# Can I get similar behavior in Windows 10 when I press the "Super" key as I do in GNOME?

Tags: windows-10, debian, keyboard, gnome

I spend more time on my Debian workstation at work than I do on my Windows personal laptop. As a result, my muscle memory is more geared toward Debian, and specifically GNOME 3, when it comes to keybindings.

I especially love that in GNOME 3, when I press the Super (Windows) key, it zooms out to show all windows.

I know that on my Windows 10 laptop, I can swipe up with a few (3 or 4, I forget right now) fingers to get roughly the same behavior. Is there a way -- either through modifying some settings in Windows or using a third-party solution -- that I can get the same behavior using the same key on Windows as I do on Debian?

Comment: You can (probably) do this with [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) bit you will have to work out the replacement keystrokes for zooming out yourself. See [How to remap Win key AND retain Win key + other key combos](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/83948-how-to-remap-win-key-and-retain-win-key-other-key-combos/) for a starting point.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I'll check that out (and probably delete this question if it works). Thanks!

Comment: No need to delete your question! You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)...